# Sorting ArrayList of JSONObjects by a double doesn't work

Tags: android, sorting, android-recyclerview

I'm currently creating an Android app for school but still want to give my best.
I'm pretty new to Android development and coding in general. The app is supposed to be a stock market game. (Btw, I'm German, so there might be some German variables)
So I want to sort my RecyclerView containing shares. It works alphabetically but not by worth.
I can guarantee that the name `"worth"` of the double in the JSONObject is correct. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class CompanyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CompanyAdapter.viewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private CustomFilter filter;
    private ArrayList<JSONObject> jObjList;
    private final String keyName;
    private final String keyWorth;
    private final String keyChange;

    public final static int SORT_ALPHABETICALLY = 0;
    public final static int SORT_ALPHABETICALLY_REVERSE = 1;
    public final static int SORT_BY_WORTH = 2;
    public final static int SORT_BY_WORTH_REVERSE = 3;

    public CompanyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<JSONObject> jObjList) {
        this.jObjList = jObjList;
        Context c = context;

        keyName = c.getResources().getString(R.string.nameCompany);
        keyWorth = c.getResources().getString(R.string.worthCompany);
        keyChange = c.getResources().getString(R.string.changeCompany);

        sort(SORT_ALPHABETICALLY);
    }

    //left out some unnecessary code

    public void sort (int sorting) {
        if (jObjList.size()>1) {
            switch (sorting) {
                case SORT_ALPHABETICALLY:
                    sortAlphabetically();
                    break;

                case SORT_ALPHABETICALLY_REVERSE:
                    sortAlphabeticallyReverse();
                    break;

                case SORT_BY_WORTH:
                    sortByWorth();
                    break;

                case SORT_BY_WORTH_REVERSE:
                    sortByWorthReverse();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void sortAlphabetically () {
        Collections.sort(jObjList, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(JSONObject j1, JSONObject j2) {
                try {
                    return j1.getString(keyName).compareToIgnoreCase(j2.getString(keyName));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void sortAlphabeticallyReverse () {
        sortAlphabetically();
        Collections.reverse(jObjList);
    }

    private void sortByWorth () {
        Collections.sort(jObjList, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(JSONObject j1, JSONObject j2) {
                try {
                    return Double.compare(j1.getDouble(keyWorth), j2.getDouble(keyWorth));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSONException", e.getMessage());
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void sortByWorthReverse () {
        sortByWorth();
        Collections.reverse(jObjList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to replace

```
return Double.compare(j1.getDouble(keyWorth), j2.getDouble(keyWorth));
```

with

```
System.out.print("VALUE1: "+j1.getDouble(keyWorth));
System.out.print("VALUE2: "+j2.getDouble(keyWorth));
    return (int)(j1.getDouble(keyWorth)-j2.getDouble(keyWorth));
```

as well to make sure and debug the value print it.

and after                     `sortByWorth();`

add `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: It's printing the correct values but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I edited the comment, Did you use notifyDataSetChanged(); ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the values of the objects you are comparing within the console?

Since you are reading in the values as a string, perhaps they will not be giving the result you expect.

Furthermore, what operation is the compare function performing?

Comment: I have checked the value and the recycler indeed isn't sorted, if that's what you meant.
What values are you talking about?
You can see it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
return Double.compare(j1.getDouble(keyWorth), j2.getDouble(keyWorth));
```

In sortByWorth method, to:

```
return j1.getDouble(keyWorth).compareTo(j2.getDouble(keyWorth))
```

Try it..

Comment: The normal double doesn't have the method compareTo. That's a string's method.
Should I try converting the doubles to Doubles?

Comment: Ye try something like this:  Double double1 = new Double(1.1);
    Double double2 = new Double("1.2");
    double1.compareTo(double2);

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Sorry, that's a stupid error.